Change mirror when installing Ubuntu 24.04
My install of Ubuntu 24.04 fails when it tries to download some packages from the pk mirror, stating the reason that a sync might be in progress. I have tried this multiple times, even waiting for couple of hours between attempts but still get the same issue. Is there a way I can change the mirror for the installer to use the global mirror instead of the pk one?

While installing, don't connect to internet, and don't choose to apply updates. Then it will install without downloading from any mirror.
Once you have installed, apply the updates using the update manager app.
In case the issue persists after the offline installation, change the mirror using the Software & Updates tool.
